# Schedule tasks in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, emr

I am running a pyspark application which consists of a single stage. The number of tasks in a stage depends on the number of partitions and hence multiple tasks in a stage are present. I want to schedule the tasks depending on the partition size it is carrying. For example - The tasks with larger partitions should be scheduled first.

Is there any way to schedule tasks in a spark job with our own algorithm?

Comment: No, that's not possible (if only you want to implement it yourself in Spark) :D
Btw, generally, you should try to keep partition size more or less equal, for faster processing. E.g. after `filter` operation *sometimes* it might be useful to call `repartition` to equalize the data.

Comment: @VladislavVarslavans Actually in my use case, I am reading files from s3 using sc.wholeTextFiles() which return a Paired RDD and also one file should reside in a single partition. So repartition is a no go. Well, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Actually if having whole file is not a requirement from the perspective of further processing - you can still `repartition` your data, by using `flatMap` to have RDD of file lines and after that `repartition`. Or you can have PairRDD of `(fileName, singleLine)` after `flatMap` if required.